# Solution of book "A course in the theory of groups" by Robinson

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation

Someone knows if there is a book or some links in which are solved the exercises contained in "A course in the theory of groups" written by Derek Robinson?

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://users.metu.edu.tr/matmah/Graduate-Algebra-Solutions/grouptheory-1.pdf) could help? Since this is a graduate textbook which is neither too new nor too popular, I wouldn't expect for solutions to be publicly available.

Comment: This was posted a while ago, but I was thinking of putting together a solutions manual for this book, especially if you are still interested. I've walked through a few chapters anyway. Are there any particular chapters you're interested in?

Comment: I would be interested in a solutions manual for this book.

Comment: Check some of my questions here, @SteveMitchell. I asked a bunch of them from this book. They were answered quite well.